# Unity3D webpage connection

Tags: javascript, c#, unity-game-engine, networking

I started to work on project in Unity but I got stuck on a web connection.

Can I use inside unity to messages spitted out from a Website as Log(message)?
Website is on JS with some JS libs

I want to use them as variable/inputs for my project.

Can I use them? How?

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can. Unity documentation has a quite nice code sample about retrieving from the web: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.Get.html

You can execute the code on regular basis, polling the web URI for messages. In case your website exposes an API to pick the messages from a queue is even better. In such a case, there is a great free asset that makes it really easy to do: https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/network/rest-client-for-unity-102501

I hope this helps ;)

~Pino